# tcsh and matching [0-9]

Tags: tcsh

I have a rather odd situation where `[0-9]` matching is not working under `tcsh` (but working under `csh` and `bash`). here is an example:

```
muon:~/tmp.52 ls
a0  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6  apollo_help.docx*
muon:~/tmp.53 ls a[4-9]
a0  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
muon:~/tmp.54 csh
%m:%B%~%b.%h ls a[4-9]
a4  a5  a6
%m:%B%~%b.%h exit
%m:%B%~%b.%h exit
muon:~/tmp.55 bash
muon:~/tmp$ ls a[4-9]
a4  a5  a6
muon:~/tmp$ exit
exit
muon:~/tmp.56 ls a[4-9]
a0  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
```

I have played with locale settings but it did not fix the problem. the OS is ubuntu. Interestingly, on another ubuntu system, `[0-9]` matching worked as expected under all 3 shells (`tcsh` included). It seemed like some funny things are hiding at the system (not user) level. what could that be? thanks very much.

Comment: Just for the record, can you include the output of `echo $version` from the tcsh please? Was it installed from the Ubuntu repository or by some other means?

Comment: I get this same strange behavior on Debian bullseye's tcsh (`tcsh 6.21.00 (Astron) 2019-05-08 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,nd,color,filec`), while `a[456789]` works as expected.

Comment: tcsh 6.21.00 (Astron) 2019-05-08 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,nd,color,filec.

Comment: sorry btw the tcsh came with the OS (ubuntu 20.04). thanks.

Comment: Fixed in 6.22. See conversation at https://mailman.astron.com/pipermail/tcsh/2019-November/000039.html

Comment: thanks much. great to know. was going crazy for a while. btw, 6.20 was fine. so a 6.21 thing.

Comment: well i downloaded 6.22 from ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/tcsh/tcsh-6.22.04.tar.gz. compiled and tried it. 6.22.04 is giving me the exact same problem as described in my original post. tcsh --version showed "tcsh 6.22.04 (Astron) 2021-04-26 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec". not sure what is going on now.